# Security Report - patch 8788

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

Patch 8788 is available for <= 1.9.2.4.

I have 1.9.3.4.

How can I fix the issues addressed?

[image]

Comment: Install the patch?

Comment: It's not available for my version. It's for older versions only.

Comment: Where is it showing that message?

Comment: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788

Comment: Maybe you or something in your team modified the core files and thus it is unsafe again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch 8788 removed vulnerable (and unused) Flash (*.swf) files. However, it appears you installed version 1.9.3.4 over an old copy, and the vulnerable files were not automatically removed.

You can fix the warning (and risk) by removing the *.swf files.